# Hold subscribe method with custom handler nats golang

Tags: go, nats.io

I am writing wrapper on top of nats client in golang, I want to take handler function which can be invoked from consumer once I get the message from nats server.
I want to hold custom subscribe method until it receives the message from nats.

Publish:

```
func (busConfig BusConfig) Publish(service string, data []byte) error {
    pubErr := conn.Publish(service, data)
    if pubErr != nil {
        return pubErr
    }
    return nil
}
```

Subscribe:

```
func (busConfig BusConfig) Subscribe(subject string, handler func(msg []byte)) {
    fmt.Println("Subscrbing on : ", subject)

    //wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    //wg.Add(1)
    subscription, err := conn.Subscribe(subject, func(msg *nats.Msg) {
        go func() {
            handler(msg.Data)
        }()
        //wg.Done()
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Subscriber error : ", err)
    }
    //wg.Wait()
    defer subscription.Unsubscribe()

}
```

test case:

```
func TestLifeCycleEvent(t *testing.T) {
    busClient := GetBusClient()
    busClient.Subscribe(SUBJECT, func(input []byte) {
        fmt.Println("Life cycle event received :", string(input))
    })

    busClient.Publish(SUBJECT, []byte("complete notification"))
}
```

I am seeing message is published but not subscribed, I tried to hold subscribe method using waitgroup but I think this is not the correct solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't see the message being delivered because `Subscribe` is an async method that spawns a goroutine to handle the incoming messages and call the callback.

Straight after calling `busClient.Publish()` your application exits. It does not wait for anything to happen inside `Subscribe()`.

When you use `nats.Subscribe()`, you usually have a long-running application that exits in specific conditions (like receiving a shutdown signal). WaitGroup can work here, but probably not for real applications, just for tests.

You should also call `Flush()` method on NATS connection to ensure all buffered messages have been sent before exiting the program.

If you want a synchronous method, you can use `nats.SubscribeSync()`

Check out examples here: https://natsbyexample.com/examples/messaging/pub-sub/go

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding, I think in NATs we need to respond to the message even if we are not providing the reply address, so it can respond to the message.

```
func (busConfig BusConfig) Subscribe(subject string, handler func(msg []byte)) {
    subscription, err := conn.Subscribe(subject, func(msg *nats.Msg) {
        go func() {
            handler(msg.Data)
            msg.Respond(nil)
        }()
      })
   }
```

Comment: No, that's incorrect.
You don't need to respond to anything.
If you respond to a message that does not have reply subject, it will return an error:
`nats: message does not have a reply`

Comment: I am not providing any reply address and I am not seeing any error, and it hold my subscribe method

Comment: because error is not handled. Change `msg.Respond(nil)` into

```if err := msg.Respond(); err != nil {
   fmt.Printf("error from Respond: %v\n", err)
}```

Please read my response carefully. It's about Go concurrency (and concurrency in general), not nats library. You're not waiting for the goroutine to finish, so it's race'y.